# Image just won't load no matter what on HTML

Tags: html, css, web

What my dir looks like:

[image: screenshot of dir]

I've doubled checked the name, the location everything, but it just shows the default no image found icon image. My code for the picture is `<img src="img.png">`. I tried changing the image, still no fix. When I hover over the `img.png` is says
[Follow link](file:///c:/Users/mathe/OneDrive/Documents/Data analysis/Python/CHAT-BOT/templates/img.png) (ctrl + click), so surely it should work?

Full html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>MJChat Bot</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="img.png" alt="Italian Trulli">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Welcome to MJ Chatbot</h1>
      <hr>
      <br>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-9">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="question" id="question">
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="submit-button">Send</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <p id="response"></p>
          </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>

      jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        $("#submit-button").click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();

          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/chatbot",
            data: {
                question: $("#question").val()
            },
            success: function(result) {
            $("#response").append("<br><br><img src='picture.jpg'/> You: "+$("#question").val()+ "<br><br><img src='picture.jpg'/> MJBot: "+result.response);
            $("#question").val("")
            },
            error: function(result) {
                alert('error');
            }
          });

        });

      });


    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Theh path you specified above will work if your html file and image are in the same directory, if your image is in an image folder you need to change it to reflect such i.e img/picture.jpg

Comment: I see that your file path is referencing an image from your OneDrive folder. Is it possible the image isn't locally stored and needs to be downloaded?

Comment: the img is locally stored it in the exact same location as the index.html

Comment: I have added a link to an img of what my directory looks like in the question